# Compare two arrays of word with partial string for search bar

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, partial

I'm a newbie, and I try to learn to set a search function for finding recipes with ingredients, but I'm stuck with the partial string...

I want to find recipe even if I type partial string (like "apple" for "apples" or "choc" for "chocolate"), but I want to return only the recipes with the full list of ingredients matching the input (if someone type "apple juice" he must not find "apple pie")

How to find the recipe even if the input word is not complete as the recipe's ingredients ?

If someone can help me...

Thank you

I tried to put a simple code that explain what I got so far:

```
const applePie = ["apples", "pie"]
const getRecipe = function (input, recipe){
recipe.forEach((ingredient) => {
        input.every((el) => recipe.includes(el)) ? console.log(recipe) : console.log("nothing found");
      })
}

const test1 = ["apple"]
const test2 = ["apples"]
const test3 = ["apples", "juice"]

getRecipe(test1, applePie);
getRecipe(test2, applePie);
getRecipe(test3, applePie);
```

Comment: try to modify your input as `new Array(input.join(" "))` at the first place inside your getRecipe function?

Comment: It's changing nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes all the search keys, and verifies that each key can be assigned to one ingredient of the recipe. If it can not find a match for a search key in any of the ingredients of the recipe, the code will return false for the given recipe. Call the method with your various recipes, and you will get all recipes that match.

```js
const recipeMatchesIngredients = function (input, recipe){
  return input.every((el) => (recipe.find((ingredient) => ingredient.startsWith(el))));
}

const applePie = ["apples", "flower"];

console.log(recipeMatchesIngredients(["app", "flower"], applePie)); // true
console.log(recipeMatchesIngredients(["app", "powder"], applePie)); // false
console.log(recipeMatchesIngredients(["apples", "juice"], applePie)); // false
console.log(recipeMatchesIngredients(["app", "flower", "pow"], applePie)); // false
```

Comment: Your logic seems good but my recipes are listed like this : https://jsfiddle.net/qot1y0xa/ and i can't find how i can adapt on it (because of the "ingredient.ingredient" thing in the objects)

Comment: Okay i find how to adapt, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to improve the data structure of your search dictionary, that will superiorly simplify your code, regardless of your language. So, say, if you had this data structure instead :

```
const cookbook = [
{
  recipe : "apple pie",
  ingredients: ["apple", "pie"]
},
{
  recipe : "apple juice",
  ingredients: ["apple", "juice"]
},
{
  recipe : "milk shake",
  ingredients: ["milk", "shake"]
},
{
  recipe : "chocolate",
  ingredients: ["cocoa", "sugar"]
}
]
```

Then your search would be massively simplified into :

```
// will return the recipe that has "apple" in it's recipe key search
const relevantRecipe = cookbook.filter((cooks) => cooks.recipe.includes("apple"))
console.log(relevantRecipe)
```

Comment: Actually my json is like that : https://jsfiddle.net/xoufd4gv/14/

And i can't apply includes on it...

Comment: Oh okay, it already seems that you've found your answer, but as you said in the question, you're new to this, so I thought that you were doing an experiment or something, regardless... please add these kind of context next time in your question, it will help massively when you get an answer